# Galaxy S not detected, how do I make it work?

Tags: android, samsung

Can anyone please provide the necessary steps to connect a Samsung Galaxy S with Ubuntu 10.10 please? I was thinking that perhaps it could detect something, but it doesn't, Anyone succeeded ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine works.

Heres what you have to do.

1. On phone goto Settings->Wireless and network->USB settings
2. Change option to Mass storage or Ask on connection
3. Connect phone to Ubuntu PC
4. If you clicked on Ask on connection select mass storage on your phone

Your phone should now be recognized.

Comment: As a warning, it does take a while sometimes (~30 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the computer is not detecting the phone because there isnt enabled for debugging mode. Although un-necessary to setup your Mobile in debug mobile, you should try the following steps:

Create this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` Make sure it contains the following lines. The idVendor is for Samsung. For HTC, replace `04e8` with `0bb4`.

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666"`

Now execute:

`chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`